# Difference between a Normal class and a MVC class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, model-view-controller

Can anyone define the difference between a normal class and an MVC class?

Comment: can you be more clear about 'blank class' ? check what class they inherit from.  Give examples

Comment: C# and MVC are completely unrelated ideas.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. If your using C# and MVC and create a new 'class' then it will be a C# class. There is no 'MVC Class'. You can inherit from other MVC classes such as a controller but that is different.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a pattern which can be implemented in any programming language. You can use Java rather than C#. When you say an empty Class, it has nothing to do with MVC pattern as it could be a class in C#/VB.Net/Java etc.

Answer (score 0):

"MVC" (Model–view–controller) is a software development architecture or pattern.

"Class" is an object-oriented programming term that is templates used to create objects, which are instances of that class.

There is no such thing as "MVC class".